# How can I redefine stdin to point to the console after using file redirection in Unix?

Tags: c, unix

I am working in Unix and I am supposed to first read in text through redirection and then ask the user to enter in a specific character and count how many times it is in the character array.

```
const int MAX = 8000;
int input = 1;
int i = 0;
char text[MAX], letter;
while(input != 0)
{
    scanf("%c", &text[i]);
    if(text[i] == '0')
        input = 0;
    i++;
}
printf("\n%s",text);

printf("\nEnter a letter to search for in the text: ");
scanf("%c", &letter)
```

Currently, I am printing the correct file through redirection, however my second `scanf` is being skipped.  I am redirecting the file using the command: `./a.out < filename.txt`.

If I try and print the character `letter` then it will result in nothing. It must be reading the `\n` from inside the empty lines of the text file still.  How do I stop the `scanf` from reading the same text file and let me enter a letter from my keyboard in the console? As an assignment I HAVE to use the command `./a.out < filename.txt`.

Comment: Thinking about this, it may be an xy problem (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Really the exercise is to write a `grep` like utility and the intended solution is probably to pass the character you are searching for as a command line argument rather than ask for it interactively (just like the `grep` command). While accessing the terminal directly is one way to do it, probably better to stick with standard approach to this kind of thing on Unix like systems (most utilities aren't interactive at all).

Answer (score 5):

The `freopen()` function is exactly what you're looking for. You just need to use it to (re)open `/dev/tty` as `stdin`. `/dev/tty` is a special file referring to the terminal that started the program.

From [the manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/freopen.3p.html):

> The `freopen()` function opens the file whose name is the string pointed to by `pathname` and associates the stream pointed to by `stream` with it. The original stream (if it exists) is closed.  The `mode` argument is used just as in the `fopen()` function.
>
> [...]
>
> **The primary use of the `freopen()` function is to change the file associated with a standard text stream (`stderr`, `stdin`, or `stdout`)**.

Here's an example:

```
// ...

FILE *tty;

tty = freopen("/dev/tty", "r", stdin);
if (tty == NULL) {
    perror("Unable to open terminal for reading");
    exit(1);
}

printf("Enter a letter to search for in the text: ");

// Now scanf will read from the console where the process started.
scanf("%c", &letter);
```

---

By the way, your program has some issues. You could read past the end of your `text` array, you don't correctly terminate it with a NUL character, and you also don't check for errors. A more correct version would be:

```
const size_t MAX = 8000;
char text[MAX];
size_t i;
int c;

for (i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
{
    c = fgetc(stdin);

    if (c == EOF)
        break;

    text[i] = (char)c;
}

text[i] = '\0';

puts(text);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to do this, probably the easiest is just to open `/dev/tty` which is a special device referring the terminal attached to the current process. I don't recommend replacing `stdin` as then you will lose access to your file which is redirected there. Instead just use a different file pointer and use functions like `fscanf` and `fgetc`. Eg:

```
FILE *tty = fopen("/dev/tty", "r");

// fopen will return NULL if there is no attached terminal
if(NULL == tty)
{
     fputs("Failed opening /dev/tty", stderr);
}
else
{
    printf("\nEnter a letter to search for in the text: ");

    // Read a character from the terminal
    char search = fgetc(tty);

    // Now you can still read from the file on stdin and search for
    // your letter without needing an array (which may not be large
    // enough for the whole file)
    char ch;
    int count = 0;
    while(EOF != (ch = getchar())
    {
        if(ch == search)
            ++count;
    }

    printf("%d occurrences of %c\n", count, search);
}
```

For more information on `/dev/tty` and other similar special files, see: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/60641/linux-difference-between-dev-console-dev-tty-and-dev-tty0

Comment: Should probably open it `"rw"` and also do the prompts on it.